# Batch ping sweep for octet 2 and 3

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

I'm trying to write a script that will ping 10.x.x.185 for over 600 locations, and then export to a text file. I know >> can be used to append to a text file.
The IP ranges are as follows: 10.0.1.185, all the way up to 10.50.2.185, incrementing by 1 each time. I see an issue being at 10.0.255.185...

Bonus if I can have a pass and fail in two different files.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The loop can be accomplished with two `for /L` loops, and piping output to two separate files is a little trickier, but still possible.

```
@echo off

:: Get the vast majority of the IP addresses
for /L %%A in (0,1,49) do (
    for /L %%B in (0,1,255) do (
        (ping 10.%%A.%%B.185>nul&&echo 10.%%A.%%B.185>>success.txt)||echo 10.%%A.%%B.185>>failure.txt
    )
)

:: Get the 10.50.x.185 range separately since it only goes from 0 to 2
for /L %%A in (0,1,2) do (
    (ping 10.50.%%A.185>nul&&echo 10.50.%%A.185>>success.txt)||echo 10.50.%%A.185>>failure.txt
)
```

The `&&` means "only do this part if the prior command was successful," and the `||` means "only do this if the prior command failed.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way in batch files to iterate over a list of consecutive numeric values is to use a `for /l` command. In your case, as you need two different series, you will need two nested `for /l` loops, one for each octet.

But as there are differences in the inner loop depending on the value of the outer loop, i will use environment variables to define how the inner loop should behave for each of the outer values.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Get a carriage return into a variable to later show progress in console
    for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "CR=%%a"

    rem Define the ranges that will be used for each of the network octets
    rem Values are those in for /l command: start step end
    set "octetA=0 1 50"
    for /l %%a in (%octetA%) do set "octetB%%a=1 1 255"
    set "octetB50=1 1 2"

    rem Iterate over the addresses. 
    rem Two streams are used to send the sucess/failure addresses to
    rem the correct log file. That way we avoid having to open/write/close
    rem each file for each write operation.

    7>"sucess.txt" 8>"failure.txt" (
        for /l %%a in (%octetA%) do for /l %%b in (!octetB%%a!) do (
            rem Show current ip being tested to console
            <nul set /p"=Testing 10.%%a.%%b.185!CR!"

            rem Execute ping command and send the address to the
            rem adecuate output stream depending on sucess/failure
            ( ping -n 1 10.%%a.%%b.185 2>nul | find "TTL=" >nul
            ) && (>&7 echo 10.%%a.%%b.185)||(>&8 echo 10.%%a.%%b.185)
        )
    )
    echo IP address testing finished
```